# resource declaration nested in collection block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing

Below routes seem to work as expected, allowing `GET /widgets/skins`
    resources :widgets do
      collection do
        resources :skins, only: "index"
       end
    end

I can't seem to find this form in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources only the regular:

```
resources :widgets do
  collection do
    get :skins, to: "Skins#index"
  end
end
```

Is the first example an official feature I can rely on? If so, can you point me to appropriate docs?

I'm using Rails 3.2.9.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get :skins, action: "index"`. It would generate exactry the same route and it was described in doc you linked upper

Comment: Uhm, wouldn't it route to Widgets#index? I wanted to widgets/skins to route to skins controller, not widgets. I know there are other ways to do it, but want to know if the form my coworker intuitively and accidentally used is correct.

Comment: you can also specify :controller => "skins". but i would probably move it outside of the resource to simple match like `match "/widgets/skins" => "skins#index", as: :widgets` and `resources :widgets, :except => [:index]`

Comment: I ended up making this an action on widgets collection. However I'm still interested if code from my example is expected behaviour that should survive Rails upgrades and if I missed it in the docs.